# Segmentation fault while running python in docker container

Tags: python, docker

I am trying to run [this](https://github.com/mitre/cascade-server.git) Github project on docker on my machine. Here is my docker file that I am running after cloning the project on my local machine.

```
FROM python:3

RUN mkdir -p /opt/cascade-server
WORKDIR /opt/cascade-server
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
COPY docker_defaults.yml conf/defaults.yml

CMD /bin/bash docker_start.sh
```

All my configurations are correct and working fine. When I run the project without docker containers, it runs correctly. When I build Docker containers to install it, it does not ends on `python cascade.py -vv` when running the below shell script from the last line of docker.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f "conf/cascade.yml" ]; then
   echo "cascade.yml found. Using existing configuration."
else
   echo "cascade.yml not found. Generating new config file from defaults"
   python cascade.py --setup_with_defaults
fi

python cascade.py -vv
```

All the logs are showing correct results till the last line executes from the shell script. Here is the error when the last line executes.

```
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:241: RuntimeWarning: greenlet.greenlet size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 152 from C header, got 160 from PyObject
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:241: RuntimeWarning: greenlet.greenlet size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 152 from C header, got 160 from PyObject
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:241: RuntimeWarning: greenlet.greenlet size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 152 from C header, got 160 from PyObject
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:241: RuntimeWarning: greenlet.greenlet size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 152 from C header, got 160 from PyObject
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:241: RuntimeWarning: greenlet.greenlet size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 152 from C header, got 160 from PyObject
/opt/cascade-server/app/async_wrapper.py:44: MonkeyPatchWarning: Monkey-patching ssl after ssl has already been imported may lead to errors, including RecursionError on Python 3.6. It may also silently lead to incorrect behaviour on Python 3.7. Please monkey-patch earlier. See https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/1016. Modules that had direct imports (NOT patched): ['urllib3.util (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/__init__.py)', 'pymongo.ssl_context (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymongo/ssl_context.py)', 'urllib3.util.ssl_ (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py)']. 
  gevent.monkey.patch_all()
docker_start.sh: line 10:    18 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) python cascade.py -vv
```

python version

[image]

Comment: are you sure it's not a python version issue? seems like now you're running with 3.10 - what's the local version that worked for you?

Comment: @ItayB yeah. i just added a screenshot referring to the python version in question

Comment: cool. Did you try to use the `python:3.7` as a base image?

Comment: @ItayB i did not tr that

Comment: @ItayB it worked with python 3.7 as the base image. thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to change the base image `python:3` (which use Python 3.10) to `python:3.7` base image like your local Python interpreter.

Comment: that was new to me that python 3 base image uses 3.10 by default, btw thanks a lot